# How can I get a python compiler on chromebook?

Tags: python, installation

I'm trying to learn pygame, but the thing is that I can't, because I need an actual python compiler. Right now I just use an online compiler, but I don't think I can do that anymore, because all of the online compilers don't have pygame preinstalled.

Also, it's a Pixelbook, not a Chromebook. (Just to clarify.)

I tried installing Visual Studio Code, and all the tutorials said I need to turn on Linux or something, but when I try it, it just says "This device does not support Linux." Is there a way I could get Visual Studio Code (Or a python compiler in general) without needing Linux?